# C# Setting a maximum / minimum return of an Int or Float

Tags: c#, math, accessor

I'm looking to control the output of values to always be below `(X)` without calling an argument every time ::

*Small Example~*

```
public int CurrentSpeed;
public int MaxSpeed;
private int caracceleration;
private int Blarg;

public int CarAcceleration{
    get{ 
        Blarg = CurrentSpeed + caracceleration;
        if(Blarg >= MaxSpeed){
            Blarg = MaxSpeed
        }

        return Blarg

    set;
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this without calling arguments every time?? Sadly as the amount and complexity of numbers increase *(I'm using 3d arrays of values in my code)* this becomes a light bottleneck

Comment: Are you saying that using `MaxSpeed` in your code is causing slowness? As a side note, you don't need the `else` in your `if` statement since the `if` block already contains a return. Just makes the code a little more clean.

Comment: All code paths in your getter for CarAcceleration have a call to the getter of CarAcceleration.  That won't work.

Comment: Sorry about that :: Here, the Example should be a little less shitty now :)

Comment: Trade memory for speed...have an instance variable for Blarg, that's computed only once. But I have a hard time believing that an add and a compare are a bottleneck.

Comment: Have you actually profiled this? I don't think this will be as much of a performance problem as you might think.

Comment: @System Down :: Yes I have, its not that bad, But I was hoping I was doing something very wrong and it could be no issue at all :)

Comment: If you're really sure the addition will never overflow, you could try wrapping it all in an `unchecked { }` block. That might shave a little bit. I hate having that sort of grasping for straws stuff in my code though.

Comment: Make blarg an int?. If it is null, compute and return it. Otherwise, just return it. If anything that it is dependent on changes, set blarg to null. Use notifypropertychanged if the dependencies are outside the class that defines your property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int Speed
{
  get
  {
     return CurrentSpeed + CarAcceleration;
  {
}

public int CarAcceleration{
    get
    { 
        if(Speed >= MaxSpeed)
        {
            return MaxSpeed
        }

        return Speed;
    }
    set;
    }
```

I guess you can roll up the calculations to avoid repeating the summations in multiple places.

I recommend avoiding premature optimization. Based on your example it doesn't seem like performance will be much of an issue. Are you actually seeing performance problems?

Answer (score 3):

Right now you're doing the addition twice. I would do this:

```
get{ 
        var newSpeed = CurrentSpeed + CarAcceleration;
        if( newSpeed >= MaxSpeed){
            return MaxSpeed;
        }
        else{
            return newSpeed;
        }
}
```

In hindsight, a cleaner version of this code would be:

```
get{ 
        var newSpeed = CurrentSpeed + CarAcceleration;
        if( newSpeed >= MaxSpeed){
            newSpeed = MaxSpeed;
        }

        return newSpeed;
}
```